# Cannot use Prisma ORM in my ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS

Tags: node.js, express, prisma, ubuntu-22.04

My `glibc` version is `2.35` and Prisma requires at least `2.33` but it still does not work in my system. I can develop schemas and migrate schemas and all but the issue only arises when I try to make a query.

```
PrismaClientInitializationError: Unable to require(`/home/kaushal/Desktop/prisma/node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-3.0.x.so.node`).
```

Prisma has detected an incompatible version of the `glibc` C standard library installed in your system. This probably means your system may be too old to run Prisma. Please refer to the documentation about Prisma's system requirements: https://pris.ly/d/system-requirements

```
Details: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3)
    at dn.loadLibrary (/home/kaushal/Desktop/prisma/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:112:9956)
    at async pr.loadEngine (/home/kaushal/Desktop/prisma/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:114:447)
    at async pr.instantiateLibrary (/home/kaushal/Desktop/prisma/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:113:1762) {
  clientVersion: '5.2.0',
  errorCode: undefined
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.